# way to create fstring inside a fstring

Tags: python, string, f-string

is it possible to create a fstring inside a fstring?

what i am trying now is to create a dynamic function using eval.

my code is something like this

```
func_string = ''
for scenario in ['scene1', 'scene2']:
    for aa in ['int', 'ext']:
         func_string += f'''
             def function_{scenario}_{aa}(part):
                 print(f"this is {part}")
           '''


eval(func_string)
function_scene1_int('part1')
```

running this script will return:
this is part1

Comment: do you _need_ to use `eval`?

Comment: And what should it return? It successfully replaced {part} with "part1"

Comment: i need to create 30 function on the fly, do you have any suggestion i can do this without code out all these functions explicitly

Comment: It can work but is an anti-pattern. Dynamical creation of variables or functions is (almost) always a poor answer to a real problem.

Comment: Serge Ballesta, do you have better suggestion to create 30 callback functions as shown in the first example of https://dash.plot.ly/getting-started-part-2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a factory method like this ...

```
def factory(a, b):
    def g(c):
        print(f'this is {c}')
        return f'other stuff using {a}, {b} and {c}'  # if you want to
    return g
```

then use it like

```
>>> f = factory('scene1', 'int')
>>> msg = f('part1')
this is part1
>>> print(msg)
other stuff using scene1, int and part1
```

Comment: aha...i can smell the answer...:)